# Negate Func<int, bool> to return opposite bool

Tags: c#, lambda, higher-order-functions

I have a lambda that returns a function that negates the result for a given function, but I just cannot get it to work.

Example:

```
not(x => x % 2 == 0)(1) --> true  
not(x => x % 2 == 0)(2) --> false
```

My current code:

```cs
Func<Func<int,bool>, Func<int, bool>> not = y => !y;

Func<int, bool> equalTo0 = x => x == 0;

var test3 = not(equalTo0)(5);
```

This would return `false` for example, but with the not lambda it should return `true`.

Has anyone have any idea/ideas on how to change the outcome of the function?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write a lambda that takes a function and returns another function. That returned function can be written as another lambda:

```
// parentheses not necessary, just for clarity 
Func<Func<int,bool>, Func<int, bool>> not = f => (x => !f(x));
```

`f` is the function that is inputted to `not`, you then return the function `x => !f(x)`.

This can also be written as a generic method:

```
Func<T, bool> Not<T>(Func<T, bool> f) => x => !f(x);
```